# Cómo obtener el conteo de una columna por medio de un Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

buen día.

Tengo en una tabla registros de cuando re-asignas una solicitud a otro agente(usuario).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tengo 2 variables donde obtengo el conteo de re-asignaciones de dicho agente.

```
var agenteId = db.Agentes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Correo == correo).AgenteId;
var agenteReasig = db.SolicitudReasignaciones.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DeAgenteId == agenteId).DeAgenteId;
```

Donde por medio de unos viewbag, los muestro en una vista que tengo.

```
ViewBag.AgenteReasignadas = db.SolicitudReasignaciones.Where(x => x.DeAgenteId == agenteReasig).Count();
```

Y para obtener cuantas veces el "Agente" ha aceptado dicha solicitud (Que tengo una columna en la tabla llamada Aceptada). Ya he intentado pero me devuelve el total de las aceptadas de todos los agentes con estas 2 variables.

```
bool True = db.SolicitudReasignaciones.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DeAgenteId == agenteId).Aceptada;
bool agenteReasigTrue = db.SolicitudReasignaciones.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Aceptada == True).Aceptada;
```

Comment: claramente el segundo query esta mal, porque estas volviendo a filtrar sobre una lista que no esta filtrada, y entonces obtenes como vos decis todas las aceptadas... no seria mejor hacer todo en una sola sentencia?? ( y de paso, cambiar el nombre de la variable True a algo mas representativo?)

Comment: Qué pasa si la solicitud no es aceptada? `True` es `false`? En la siguiente sentencia, si el `FirstOrDefault(x => x.Aceptada == True)` no trae nada, cuando encadenes el `.Aceptada` te va a tirar un `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @gbianchi He intentado hacerlo con un groupBy seleccionando el id del DeAgente filtrando por las Aceptadas pero me devuelve todas

Comment: @Arriel No pasa nada si me devuelve null, tan solo quiero contar todas las filas que tengo "Aceptadas" de dicho ID del DeAgenteId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tan solo borre las variables de True y agenteReasigTrue, y en otra que tengo de "agenteReasig" tan solo filtre por agenteId y en el viewBag añadí otra condición de que también incluyera sí Aceptada fuera true.

```
ViewBag.AgenteAceptadas = db.SolicitudReasignaciones.Where(x => x.DeAgenteId == agenteReasig && x.Aceptada == true).Count();
```